# ActionController::UnknownFormat while using javascript format in respond_to

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am building my first app which uses javascript as a response to controller action request. I've defined `create` action like this inside my controller:

```
def create
    @cat = Cat.new(cat_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @cat.save
        format.js
      end
    end
end
```

And I've created `create.js.erb` inside `views/cats` which has a code for response. After I trigger `create` action inside my view, I receive the following error:

```
ActionController::UnknownFormat in CatsController#create
ActionController::UnknownFormat
```

How to deal with this problem? What do you recommend? I am using Rails4

Answer (score 0):

It's possible you are getting that error because you don't have a format if @cat doesn't save. This should work for you:

```
def create
  @cat = Cat.new(cat_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @cat.save
      format.js
    else
      #assuming that you are using js throughout
      format.js { render :new }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't work. I am still having troubles with this.